# Extend a python list elements on the list's declaration instead of append

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a python list

```
list2 = ['three', 'four', 'five']
```

and I want to merge it with a new one declared

```
list1 = ['one', 'two', list2, 'six']
```

and take the result of

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

instead of

```
['one', 'two', ['three', 'four', 'five'], 'six']
```

could this be possible within the declaration line?

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the list.

**Ex:**

```
list2 = ['three', 'four', 'five']
list1 = ['one', 'two', *list2, 'six']
print(list1)
```

**Output:**

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```